# Radio button css not applied inside label

Tags: css

There are list of divs in my html body. Each specifies a css class and each div has its own CSS's.  And each div has many child divs(i.e.,Multi-level hierarchy).  I have to specify many color difference in radio button.

[Issues in applying radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYhdh.jpg)
I used below code

```
.mytext > div > div > label > input {
  background-color: #e5f442!important;
}
```

Please help to resolve my issue

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I do not really understand the question nor what the goal is.
Could you provide some HTML to understand what you mean?

Comment: The CSS is being applied fine, changing the `background-color` of a radio button won't do anything though.

Answer (score 0):

Directly changing the background color of radio button won't help, you need to add css as given below..

```css
input[type=checkbox]:not(old),
input[type=radio   ]:not(old){
  width     : 2em;
  margin    : 0;
  padding   : 0;
  font-size : 1em;
  opacity   : 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label,
input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label{
  display      : inline-block;
  margin-left  : -2em;
  line-height  : 1.5em;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label > span,
input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label > span{
  display          : inline-block;
  width            : 0.875em;
  height           : 0.875em;
  margin           : 0.25em 0.5em 0.25em 0.25em;
  border           : 0.0625em solid rgb(192,192,192);
  border-radius    : 50%;
  background       : rgb(224,224,224);
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  vertical-align   : bottom;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label > span,
input[type=radio   ]:not(old):checked + label > span{
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label > span:before{
  content     : '✓';
  display     : block;
  width       : 1em;
  color       : rgb(153,204,102);
  font-size   : 0.875em;
  line-height : 1em;
  text-align  : center;
  text-shadow : 0 0 0.0714em rgb(115,153,77);
  font-weight : bold;
}

input[type=radio]:not(old):checked + label > span > span{
  display          : block;
  width            : 0.5em;
  height           : 0.5em;
  margin           : 0.125em;
  border           : 0.0625em solid rgb(115,153,77);
  border-radius    : 50%;
  background       : rgb(153,204,102);
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="option" type="radio" name="field" value="option">
  <label for="option"><span><span></span></span>Single</label>
</div>
```